# service worker stopped working after changes in app.js file

Tags: service-worker

My PWA worked fine until this morning. During programming, I changed something so that the service worker stopped working.

It is still being registered, but after disconnecting my computer from the network, the service worker does not show the offline fallback anymore.

I can't find the problem. No idea, what is going wrong.

It's not that much code, but I don't know how to break it down. I don't think the problem is in the service-worker file.

Here is my **sw.js**:

```
const staticAssets = [
    './',
    './menu.html',
    './jquery.min.js',
    './styles.css',
    './app.js',
    './images',
    './fallback.json',
    './images/system/offline.png',
    'sw.js'    
];




self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
    const cache = await caches.open('static-assets');
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    const req = event.request;
    const url = new URL(req.url);

    if(url.origin === location.origin){
        event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
    }else{
        event.respondWith(networkFirst(req));
    }

});


async function cacheFirst(req){
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(req);
    return cachedResponse || fetch(req);
}

async function networkFirst(req){
    const cache = await caches.open('dynamic-content');
    try{
        const res = await fetch(req);
        cache.put(req, res.clone());
        return res;
    }catch(err){
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(req);
        return cachedResponse || caches.match('./fallback.json');
    }
}
```

If you really want to help, you might want to have a look at the actual project here. Check the **app.js** file, I guess chances are high the problem is there. You can see that the sw is not working by clicking the menu button before and after disconnect.

https://jaxpot.000webhostapp.com

the **app.js** file:

```
const apiKey = 'XYZ'
const topbar = document.querySelector('#topbar');
const highbar = document.querySelector('.stat-back.high');
const lowbar = document.querySelector('.stat-back.low');
const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');

var sourceSelector = document.querySelector('#sourceSelector');
var defaultSource = 'the-washington-post';

window.addEventListener('load', async  e => {
    //adjust topbar to mobile device
    if(typeof window.orientation != 'undefined'){
        fitScreen('orientation', window.orientation);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
            fitScreen('orientation', window.orientation)
        });
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            fitScreen('scroll', window.orientation)
        });
    }else if(typeof screen.orientation != 'undefined'){
        fitScreen(screen.orientation);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
            fitScreen('orientation', screen.orientation)
        });
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            fitScreen('scroll', screen.orientation)
        });
    }else{
        topbar.style.top="0px";
    }

    menuBtn.addEventListener('change', e => {
        toggleMenu(e.target);
    });



    updateNews();
    await updateSources();
    sourceSelector.value = defaultSource;

    sourceSelector.addEventListener('change', e => {
        updateNews(e.target.value);
    });


    if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        try{
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
            console.log(`SW registration complete`);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(`SW registration failed`);
        }
    }else{
        console.log(`SW not supported`);
    }
});




async function fitScreen(origin, deviceOrientation){
    if (Math.abs(deviceOrientation) === 90) {
        // Landscape
        highbar.style.backgroundColor="#eeeeee";
        if(window.innerWidth > 700){
            lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#eeeeee";
            lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
            lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        }else{
            lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#fff";
            lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
            lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        }
        topbar.style.cssText = "";      
    }else{
        // Portrait

        if(origin == 'orientation'){



            setTimeout(function(){

                var scrH = screen.height;
                var srcAH = screen.availHeight;
                var winH = window.innerHeight;

                if(srcAH > winH){
                    if(srcAH-winH > 20){
                        console.log("iOS - browser");
                        highbar.style.display="block";
                        lowbar.style.display="none";
                    }else{
                        console.log("new iOS - full");
                        highbar.style.display="none";
                        lowbar.style.display="block";
                        if(window.innerWidth > 700){
                            lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#eeeeee";
                            lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
                            lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                        }else{
                            lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#fff";
                            lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
                            lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                        }
                    }

                    topbar.style.cssText = "top:0px; padding-top:11px";
                }else if(winH > srcAH ){
                    console.log("old iOS - full");

                    topbar.style.cssText = "top:0px; padding-top:31px; height:80px";
                    highbar.style.display="none";
                    lowbar.style.display="none";
                }

            },100);
        }else if(origin == 'scroll'){
            if(document.querySelector('body').scrollTop > 19){
                lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#2a3443";
                lowbar.style.opacity = "1";
                lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "";
            }else{
                if(window.innerWidth > 700){
                    lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#eeeeee";
                    lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
                    lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                }else{
                    lowbar.style.backgroundColor="#fff";
                    lowbar.style.opacity = "0";
                    lowbar.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                }
            }
        }

    }  
}




async function updateNews(source = defaultSource){
    const res = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=${source}&apiKey=${apiKey}`);
    const json = await res.json();

    content.innerHTML = json.articles.map(createArticle).join('\n');
}
async function updateSources(){
    const res = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v1/sources`);
    const json = await res.json();

    sourceSelector.innerHTML = json.sources
    .map(src => `<option value="${src.id}">${src.name}</option>`)
    .join('\n')
}


function createArticle(article){
    return `
        <div class="article">
            <a href = "${article.url}">
                <h2>${article.title}</h2>
                <img src="${article.urlToImage}">
                <p>${article.description}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="devider"></div>
    `
}



async function toggleMenu(el){
      if(el.checked == true){

        var res = await fetch(`menu.html`);
        var menu = await res.text();

        content.innerHTML = menu;

        var freeSpace = window.innerHeight - (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(topbar, null).getPropertyValue("height").split("px")[0]) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content, null).getPropertyValue("height").split("px")[0]) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("footer"), null).getPropertyValue("height").split("px")[0]));
        document.querySelector('.whitespace').style.height = Math.max(freeSpace, 0) + "px";


      }else{
          updateNews(defaultSource);
      }
  }
```

Comment: It's working offline for me. One important thing to note: *never ever* cache the sw.js file. Remove it from static assets! :)

Comment: Works for me too, now. Could you explain why not to store the sw.js file in the cache?